# How to filter child tables with EF4?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, foreign-keys, filtering

I have these tables

```
CREATE TABLE parent
( 
     id               NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL, 
     name             VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) NOT NULL, 
     primary key (id), 
)

CREATE TABLE child
( 
     id               NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL, 
     name             VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) NOT NULL, 
     conclusion       DATE,
     parent_id        NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL,
)

ALTER TABLE child ADD constraint foreign key (parent_id) references parent;
```

I want to get a `List<Parent>` where each `Parent.Child` has only elements where `!CONCLUSION.HasValue()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A second option is to

```
var parents = context.Parents.ToList();
foreach(var parent in parents)
{
    var invalidChildren = parent.CHILD
        .Where(child => child.CONCLUSION.HasValue())
        .ToArray();
    foreach(var invalid in invalidChildren)
    {
        parent.CHILD.Remove(invalid);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = (from p in Parent
              select new Parent()
              {
                id = p.id,
                child = (from c in Child
                         where c.parent_id = p.id &&
                         !c.conclusion.HasValue()
                         select c).ToList() 
              }).ToList();
```

This is not tested but it should do the job

Comment: I think it will filter out all parents without valid children, also if a parent has at least one valid child then all its children will be present.

Comment: Yup...after i posted the first answer a figured out that I was wrong and updated it now

Comment: Your second version is closer, but I wonder if a `EntityCollection<Child>` will accept a `List<Child>`

Comment: There is also the problem that you are creating new Parent instances that are not attached to the database, which is a concern in my case.